# Wordpress: On hover load title of post into a specific DIV

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, hover

I'm currently working on a wordpress template where the title of a post is hidden and on hovering the post, it should be displayed on the bottom of the browser. To simplify, the post has this structure:

```
<article class="post">
   <header class="article-header">
      <h2 class="entry-title">
         Post Title
      </h2>
   </header>
   <section class="entry-content">
      Post Content
   </section>
</article>
```

Basically, I'd like to have a fixed  in the body, that sits on the bottom of the browser and when a post is hovered, the content of its child element  is passed into the . My approach so far was to have all  elements constantly fixed to the browser bottom (hidden) and on a hover, each of them will be display. That led to a couple of problems and I thought I'd might be easier to have one empty div, which just grabs the title information.

Can anyone help me with that, maybe with jQuery or php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean, something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rKhqT/5/

HTML:

```
<article class="post">
   <header class="article-header">
      <h2 class="entry-title">
         Post Title
      </h2>
   </header>
   <section class="entry-content">
      Post Content
   </section>
</article>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.entry-title {
    display: none;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS (requires jQuery) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('article.post').mouseover(function() {
        $('footer').text($(this).find('h2').text());
    });
    $('article.post').mouseout(function() {
        $('footer').text('');
    });    
});
```